# Understanding what this VBA function does

Tags: excel, vba

The function is taking Sheet as string. I dont see which worksheet the sheet is referring to. Otherwise with slight modification i could have redirected to the worksheet i wanted. While debugging, i see the error of "subscript out of range"

```
Function TextFileInfoArrayFPP(WeeksToLoad As Integer, EndingRow As Integer, StartingRow As Integer, Sheet As String) As Variant

'check and adjust for non-edited values
Sheets("REF_FPP").Visible = Visible
Sheets("REF_UPB").Visible = Visible

Dim count As Integer
count = 0
'calc the new length for the new required array
For i = 0 To EndingRow - 1
    For n = 0 To WeeksToLoad - 1
        If Sheets(Sheet).Cells(StartingRow + i, 9 + n).Value <> Sheets("REF_" & Sheet).Cells(StartingRow + i, 9 + n).Value Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next n
Next i

ReDim FPPArray(count, 3 - 1) As Variant

'print column names (Date, PPR Line Item, Value)
    FPPArray(0, 0) = "Date"
    FPPArray(0, 1) = "PPR Line Item"
    FPPArray(0, 2) = "Value"

count = 1
'this is the loop through weeks
For i = 0 To WeeksToLoad - 1
    'this is the loop through line item
    For n = StartingRow To EndingRow
        If Sheets(Sheet).Cells(n, 9 + i).Value <> Sheets("REF_" & Sheet).Cells(n, 9 + i).Value Then
            'print date
            FPPArray(count, 0) = Sheets(Sheet).Cells(3, 9 + i).Value
            'print PPR Line item
            FPPArray(count, 1) = Sheets(Sheet).Cells(n, 1).Value
            'print value
            FPPArray(count, 2) = Sheets(Sheet).Cells(n, i + 9).Value
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next n
Next i

TextFileInfoArrayFPP = FPPArray

Sheets("REF_FPP").Visible = xlHidden
Sheets("REF_UPB").Visible = xlHidden

End Function
```

**The function is taking Sheet as string. I dont see which worksheet the sheet is referring to. Otherwise with slight modification i could have redirected to the worksheet i wanted. While debugging, i see the error of "subscript out of range"**

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Find where this function is being called.  That should give you value of Sheet parameter.  Or you could simply print the value to immediate window:  debug.Print Sheet

Comment: I would guess that `sheet` is intended to be either "FPP" or "UPB" based on the hardcoded "REF_FPP" and "REF_UPB" and the line with `Sheets("REF_" & Sheet)`

Answer (score 0):

The VBA TextFileInfoArrayFPP function is a function that appears to be used in a Microsoft Excel workbook. The function takes several arguments as input, including WeeksToLoad, EndingRow, StartingRow, and Sheet. The function performs several operations on data contained in Excel spreadsheets and returns an array of output values.

Specifically, the function performed if the cells in a range of enabled cells on a given worksheet are different from the corresponding cells on another worksheet. If the cell values are different, the function adds those values to a table as rows with three columns: "Date", "PPR Line Item", and "Value". The function then returns this array as output.